# Why Increasing Collector Voltage Reduces Collector-base Capacitance

Tags: transistors, capacitance, gain, high-frequency

I'm looking at some transistor radio circuits and the book I'm following makes the following statement with regard to AC gain: "By raising the DC voltage at the collector, the internal collector-base capacitances of the transistor are reduced".

Here's a circuit to help understand what's going on:

[image]

Here the author has killed the DC gain by placing an inductor in parallel with R2 whilst leaving the AC gain intact: collector reactance (L1||R2) / emitter reactance (C3||R3).

I have a reasonable grasp of the effect of Miller Capacitance on an inverting amplifier, where the inverted output acts negatively on the input.  What I don't understand is why increasing the collector voltage acts to reduce collector-base capacitance.

Does the increase in current flowing through the collector-emitter junction have anything to do with it?

Comment: What happens to the capacitance of a diode (PN junction)  in reverse mode as a function of the (reverse) voltage ? This effect is used in varicap diodes but any PN junction exhibits this behaviour.

Comment: I have no idea.  But, if you turn your question into a fully fledged answer, you'll have made my day.

Comment: Open your favorite textbook on semiconductor physics and look it up then ! If you want to be able to work with analog circuits, this is a thing you need to know and understand. It's not hard.

Comment: Is this the same as the "Miller Effect", or is that only on FETs? I've never quite understood it either.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @FakeMoustache, a quick search for varactors gave me the intuition I needed.

Comment: @pjc50 No the "Miller effect" is an effect that is caused by the presence of a capacitor between input (base) and output (collector) and where the voltage gain is negative. This makes the capacitance look larger in size from the input. It can happen with any amplifier, BJT, FET, tube ;-) even opamp !

Comment: In this circuit, Cbc is enlarged by the miller effect. So it makes sense to keep Cbc small. You can do that by increasing the voltage at the collector.

Comment: "makes the capacitance look larger" ... to explain why: if, eg, voltage gain is 10, an input of 1Vrms will cause 10Vrms at the collector, and is 180 degrees out of phase - if the base-collector capacitance is 1pF, there is 10V through 1pF working against you, same as when you look to ground through 10pF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @FakeMoustache hinted in a comment to your question, the explanation lies in the behavior of a reverse-biased PN junction, because that's what Q1's collector-base junction is in your circuit.

From a macroscopic point of view any reverse-biased PN junction acts like a parallel-plate capacitor whose capacitance (called *transition capacitance* \$C_T\$) depends inversely on the reverse voltage \$V_R\$. The relationship is not linear, but it is approximately:

$$
C_T = K \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{V_0 + V_R}}
$$

where \$V_0\$ is the voltage gap created by the junction and \$K\$ is a constant.

**EDIT**

Struggling to remember the exact form of the formula (there are half a dozen of ways of writing down that relationship, depending on which physical parameters of the junction you want to emphasize) I found a more intuitive formula in [this Google book](https://books.google.it/books?id=dnq3HmDN1ZAC&pg=RA4-PA28&lpg=RA4-PA28&dq=pn+junction+transition+capacitance&source=bl&ots=hePfOkxOYU&sig=LimeGcbOkJxG7Vt3eiUMghgoc7Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFUQ6AEwCGoVChMIwP3Go7b5yAIVhmIPCh2tNgvc#v=onepage&q=pn%20junction%20transition%20capacitance&f=false):

$$
C_T = \dfrac{C_0}{(1 + V_R)^n}
$$

---

<sup>**Note:**
That formula has an error in it (dimensional analysis debunks it). Probably \$V_R\$ is meant to be the relative voltage with respect to some reference. I guess the correct formula should be:
$$
C_T = \dfrac{C_0}{\left(1 + \dfrac{V_R}{V_0}\right)^n}
$$</sup>

---

where \$C_0\$ is the capacitance when no bias is applied and \$n\$ depends on how the junction is doped: \$n = \frac 1 2\$ for step-graded junctions, whereas \$n=\frac 1 3 \$ for linearly-graded junctions.

Another [interesting article on the subject](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/chapter4/ch4_3.htm) (tougher semiconductor physics stuff) explains how to derive that relationship (in yet another form!).

Comment: Yep, @FakeMoustache put me on the right track and for those interested the images in this link (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varicap) give you a fair idea of what's happening.

Comment: Exactly :-) Ct goes down when Vr goes up ! The **increased** reverse voltage causes the size of the depletion layer to expand, this **decreases** the capacitance. Visualize it, now remember forever :-)